# Position absolute / relative with correct height for wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a block of text to show up as trimmed / short version then to use an animation to show the full block of text, so I've put them both into two different elements, and hide/show based on which one you can see.

Here is my sample code, the text is different but it's just for an example of what I am doing. My problem is that I need to always ensure that the green text block in **#next** shows up always after the **red** or **blue** blocks of text.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="short">
            Only a small amount of text
        </div>
        <div id="long" style="display: none">
            A much longer text with <br>
            some lines<br>
            ...<br>
            ...<br>
            ...<br>
            ...<br>
            Surprise!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="next">
    Other content<br>
    to show up<br>
    here<br>
    <button onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE TEXT</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
toggle = function() {
    var lElem = $('#long');
    var sElem = $('#short');
    if (lElem.css('display') == 'none') {
        sElem.hide('fast');
        lElem.show('fast');
    } else {
        lElem.hide('fast');
        sElem.show('fast');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: auto;
}

#parent {
    position: absolute;
}

#short, #long {
    position: relative;
}

#short {
    background-color: red;
}

#long {
    background-color: blue;
}

#next {
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

JsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/6v9fyg2g/

I have tried playing around with position: **absolute** and **relative** as well as adding **height: 100%** but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want as long as `next` is not a child of `parent` and `parent` is [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

From MDN:

> `absolute`:
>       **Do not leave space for the element.** Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

*(Emphasis mine).*

What happens in this circumstance is that `parent` is placed at `(0,0)` and the rest of the layout, including `next`, **is flowed without regard for `parent`, hence `next` counts for all intents and purposes as the first element and ends up at the beginning**.

One possible solution is removing the `position: absolute` from `parent`.
Then, as you require, "the green text block in `#next` shows up always after the red or blue blocks of text", like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/6v9fyg2g/4/

You can then adjust the other properties of your `divs` (e.g. width) as you see fit.

You may want to [`display: inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) them for starters (the second option looks closer to how the `divs` appeared in your original):

http://jsfiddle.net/6v9fyg2g/8/

http://jsfiddle.net/6v9fyg2g/9/